# Obtaining A List of Car Brands from Wikipedia Using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

What I want to do is to be able to go and scrape all the makes of cars off the Wikipedia page for each of the countries and be able to get them into a dictionary.

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_car_brands
```

Right now I am currently using BeautifulSoup and found that each of these cars lies within a ul and li tag but I am not sure how to specifically get them specifically. Where the cars come from isn't really relevant and I just want to be able to get all of them into a list.

I have the current code that is able to get all of the ul tags but not sure how to go about specifying it in a better way.

```
# Import packages
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Specify url of the web page
source = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_car_brands').read()
# Make a soup 
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

for link in soup.find_all("li"):
    print(link)
```

Any direction or idea of what I can do would be much appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Flat list with cars

Select all `<li>` that are next siblings of a `<h2>` get its texts and slice by the first list entry of 'See also' section:

```
(x:=[x.text.split('[')[0] 
        for x in soup.select('h2~ul li')
])[:x.index('Timeline of motor vehicle brands')]
```

##### Output

```
['Zanella (1948–present)', 'Anasagasti (1911–1915)', 'Andino (1967–1973)', 'ASA (1961– 1969)', 'Eniak (1983–1989)', 'Hispano-Argentina (1925–1953)', 'Industrias Aeronáuticas y Mecánicas del Estado (IAME, Mechanical Aircraft Industries of the State, 1951–1979), not to be confused with Italian American Motor Engineering', 'Industrias Kaiser Argentina (IKA, 1956–1975), United Kingdom', 'Alpha Sports (1963–present)', 'Arrow (1963–present)',...]
```

#### List of dicts with cars and country

A bit more to do but nearly the same - Select all `<h2>` that has `<ul>` as next siblings and iterate over their next siblings while the next `<h2>` follows:

```
data = []

for h in soup.select('h2:has(~ul)'):
    cars = []
    for tag in h.next_siblings:
        if tag.name == 'ul':
            for x in tag.text.split('\n'):
                cars.append(x.split('[')[0])
        elif tag.name == 'h2':
            break
            
    if 'See also' not in h.text:        
        data.append({
            'country':h.text.split('[')[0],
            'cars': cars
        })
print(data)
```

##### Output

```
[{'country': 'Argentina', 'cars': ['Zanella (1948–present)', 'Anasagasti (1911–1915)', 'Andino (1967–1973)', 'ASA (1961– 1969)', 'Eniak (1983–1989)', 'Hispano-Argentina (1925–1953)', 'Industrias Aeronáuticas y Mecánicas del Estado (IAME, Mechanical Aircraft Industries of the State, 1951–1979), not to be confused with Italian American Motor Engineering', 'Industrias Kaiser Argentina (IKA, 1956–1975), United Kingdom']}, {'country': 'Australia', 'cars': ['Alpha Sports (1963–present)', 'Arrow (1963–present)', 'Birchfield (2003–present)', 'Bolwell (1979–present)', 'Borland Racing Developments (1984–present)', 'Bufori (1986–present)', 'Bullet (1996–present)', 'Carbontech (1999–present)', 'Daytona (2002–present)', 'Devaux (2001–present)', 'DRB Sports Cars (1997–present)', 'Elfin Cars (1958–present)', 'Finch Restorations (1965–present)', 'Jacer (1995–present)', 'Joss Developments (2004–present)', 'McKernan (2012–present)', 'Minetti Sports Cars (2003–present)', 'Nota (1955–present)', 'PRB (1978–present)', 'Puma Clubman (1998–present)', 'Python (1981–present)', 'Quantum (2015–present)', 'Roaring Forties (1997–present)', 'Spartan-V (2004–present)', 'Stealth Special Vehicles (2004–present)', 'Stohr Cars (1991–present)', 'Ascort (1958–1960)', 'Austin (1954–1983)', 'Australian Six (1919–1930)', 'Australis (1897–1907)', 'Birchfield (2003–2004)', 'Blade (2008–2013)', 'Buchanan', 'Buckle (1955–1959)', 'Bush Ranger (1977–2016)', 'Caldwell Vale (1907–1913)', 'Cheetah', 'Chrysler (1957–1981)', 'Ford (1925–2016) (continues as a brand applied to imported cars)', 'FPV (2002–2014)', 'Giocattolo (1986–1989)', 'Goggomobil (1958–1961)', 'Hartnett (1949–1955)', 'Holden (1948–2017) (continues as a brand applied to imported cars)', 'HSV (1987–2017)', 'Honda', 'Ilinga (1974-1975)', 'Kaditcha', 'Leyland (1973–1982)', 'Lloyd-Hartnett (1957–1962)', 'Lonsdale (1982–1983) (Cars produced and exported by Mitsubishi Australia and sold in the UK by the Colt Car Company under the Lonsdale brand.)', 'Mercedes-Benz (1890–present)', 'Mitsubishi (1980–2008) (The brand continued to be used in Australia for fully imported cars after 2008.)', 'Morris (1947–1973)', 'Nissan (1983–1992) (The brand continued to be used in Australia for fully imported cars after 1992.)', 'Pellandini (1970–1978)', 'Pioneer', 'Purvis Eureka (1974–1991)', 'Shrike (1988–1989)', 'Southern Cross (1931–1935)', 'Statesman (1971–1984)', 'Tarrant (1900–1907)', 'Toyota, Australian production finished (1963–2017)', 'Volkswagen', 'Zeta (1963–1965)']}, {'country': 'Austria', 'cars': ['Eurostar Automobilwerk', 'KTM', 'Magna Steyr', 'ÖAF', 'Puch', 'Steyr Motors GmbH', 'Rosenbauer', 'Tushek&Spigel Supercars', 'Austro-Daimler (1889–1934)', 'Austro-Tatra (1934–1948)', 'Custoca (also known as Custoka) (1966–1988)', 'Denzel (1948–1959)', 'Felber Autoroller (1952–1953)', 'Gräf & Stift (1902–2001)', 'Grofri (1921–1931)', 'Libelle (1952–1954)', 'Lohner-Porsche (1900–1905)', 'Möve 101', 'Steyr automobile', 'Steyr-Daimler-Puch']}, {'country': 'Azerbaijan', 'cars': ['GA (1986–present)', 'Khazar (2018–present)', 'NAZ (2010–present)', 'Aziz (2005–2010)']}, {'country': 'Belgium', 'cars': ['Ecar (2015–present)', 'Edran (1984–present)', 'Gillet (1982–present)', 'Imperia Automobiles (2008–present)', 'ADK (1930)', 'Alatac (1913–1914)', 'Alberta (1906)', 'Alfa Legia (1914)', 'ALP (1920)', 'Altona (1946)', 'AMA (1913)', 'Antoine (1903)', "d'Aoust (1927)", 'Apal (1998)', 'Aquila (1903)', 'Astra (1931)', 'ATA', 'Auto Garage (1911)', 'Auto-Mixte (1906–1912)', 'Avior (1947)', 'Bastin (1909)', 'Beckett & Farlow (1908)', 'Belga (1921)', 'Belga-Rise (1935)', 'Belgica (1909)', 'Bercley (1900)', 'Bovy (1914)', 'Cambier (1898)', 'CAP (1914)', 'Catala (1914)', 'CIE (1898)', "CLA (Compagnie Liégeoise d'Automobiles) (1901)", 'Claeys-Flandria (1955)', 'Coune (1947)', 'Cyclecars R&D (1921)', 'Dasse (1924)', 'De Cosmo (1908)', 'De Wandre (1923)', 'DéChamps (1906)', 'Delecroix (1899)', 'Delin (1901)', 'Direct (1905)', 'Dyle & Bacalan (1906)', 'Escol (1938)', 'Excelsior (1904–1932)', 'Fab (1914)', 'FD (1925)', 'Fif (1914)', 'Flaid (1921)', 'FN (1935)', 'Fondu (1912)', 'Frenay (1914)', 'Germain (1901)', 'Hermes (1909)', 'Hermes-Mathis (1914)', 'Imperia (1906–1948)', 'Imperia-Abadal (1913–1917)', 'Jeecy-Vea (1926)', 'Jenatzy (Société Générale des Transports Automobiles) (1905)', 'Juwel (1928)', 'Kleinstwagen (1952)', 'Knap (moved to France in 1899 or 1900) (1909)', 'L&B', 'Linon (1914)', 'Loza (1925)', 'Matthieu (1906)', 'Matthys Frères et Osy (1927)', 'Mécanique et Moteurs (1906)', 'Meeussen (1972)', 'Métallurgique (1913)', 'Miesse (1926)', 'Minerva (1939)', 'Nagant (1927)', 'Oracle (2005)', 'P.L.M. (Keller) (1955)', 'P-M (1924)', 'Peterill (1899)', 'Pieper (1903)', 'Pipe (1922)', 'R.A.L. (1914)', 'Ranger (General Motors brand) (1970–1978)', 'Royal Star (1910)', 'Rumpf (1899)', 'S.C.H. (1928)', 'Sava (1923)', 'SOMEA', 'Speedsport (1927)', 'Springuel (1912)', 'Taunton (1922)', 'Turner-Miesse (1913)', 'Vanclee (1989)', 'Vincke (1905)', 'Vivinus (1912)', 'Widi (1960)', 'Wilford (1901)', 'Zelensis (1962)']},...]
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to get all list items with no classes (which will skip the index at the top), then split that list by the first occurrence of `'Timeline of motor vehicle brands'`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Specify url of the web page
source = urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_car_brands').read()
# Make a soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
#get all list items
list_items = [i.get_text() for i in soup.find_all('li', class_=None)]
#split list_items by 'Timeline of motor vehicle brands'
list_items = list_items[:list_items.index('Timeline of motor vehicle brands')]
#remove citations from strings
list_items = [i.split('[')[0] for i in list_items]
```

Output:

```
['Zanella (1948–present)', 'Anasagasti (1911–1915)', 'Andino (1967–1973)', 'ASA (1961– 1969)', 'Eniak (1983–1989)', 'Hispano-Argentina (1925–1953)', 'Industrias Aeronáuticas y Mecánicas del Estado (IAME, Mechanical Aircraft Industries of the State, 1951–1979), not to be confused with Italian American Motor Engineering', 'Industrias Kaiser Argentina (IKA, 1956–1975), United Kingdom', 'Alpha Sports (1963–present)', 'Arrow (1963–present)', 'Birchfield (2003–present)', 'Bolwell (1979–present)', 'Borland Racing Developments (1984–present)', 'Bufori (1986–present)', 'Bullet (1996–present)', 'Carbontech (1999–present)', 'Daytona (2002–present)', 'Devaux (2001–present)', 'DRB Sports Cars (1997–present)', 'Elfin Cars (1958–present)', 'Finch Restorations (1965–present)', 'Jacer (1995–present)', 'Joss Developments (2004–present)', 'McKernan (2012–present)', 'Minetti Sports Cars (2003–present)', 'Nota (1955–present)', 'PRB (1978–present)', 'Puma Clubman (1998–present)', 'Python (1981–present)', 'Quantum (2015–present)', 'Roaring Forties (1997–present)', 'Spartan-V (2004–present)', 'Stealth Special Vehicles (2004–present)', 'Stohr Cars (1991–present)', 'Ascort (1958–1960)', 'Austin (1954–1983)', 'Australian Six (1919–1930)', 'Australis (1897–1907)', 'Birchfield (2003–2004)', 'Blade (2008–2013)', 'Buchanan', 'Buckle (1955–1959)', 'Bush Ranger (1977–2016)', 'Caldwell Vale (1907–1913)', 'Cheetah', 'Chrysler (1957–1981)', 'Ford (1925–2016) (continues as a brand applied to imported cars)', 'FPV (2002–2014)', 'Giocattolo (1986–1989)', 'Goggomobil (1958–1961)', 'Hartnett (1949–1955)', 'Holden (1948–2017) (continues as a brand applied to imported cars)', 'HSV (1987–2017)', 'Honda', 'Ilinga (1974-1975)', 'Kaditcha', 'Leyland (1973–1982)', 'Lloyd-Hartnett (1957–1962)', 'Lonsdale (1982–1983) (Cars produced and exported by Mitsubishi Australia and sold in the UK by the Colt Car Company under the Lonsdale brand.)', 'Mercedes-Benz (1890–present)', 'Mitsubishi (1980–2008) (The brand continued to be used in Australia for fully imported cars after 2008.)', 'Morris (1947–1973)', 'Nissan (1983–1992) (The brand continued to be used in Australia for fully imported cars after 1992.)', 'Pellandini (1970–1978)', 'Pioneer', 'Purvis Eureka (1974–1991)', 'Shrike (1988–1989)', 'Southern Cross (1931–1935)', 'Statesman (1971–1984)', 'Tarrant (1900–1907)', 'Toyota, Australian production finished (1963–2017)', 'Volkswagen', 'Zeta (1963–1965)', 'Eurostar Automobilwerk', 'KTM', 'Magna Steyr', 'ÖAF', 'Puch', 'Steyr Motors GmbH', 'Rosenbauer', 'Tushek&Spigel Supercars', 'Austro-Daimler (1889–1934)', 'Austro-Tatra (1934–1948)', 'Custoca (also known as Custoka) (1966–1988)', 'Denzel (1948–1959)', 'Felber Autoroller (1952–1953)', 'Gräf & Stift (1902–2001)', 'Grofri (1921–1931)', 'Libelle (1952–1954)', 'Lohner-Porsche (1900–1905)', 'Möve 101', 'Steyr automobile', 'Steyr-Daimler-Puch', 'GA (1986–present)', 'Khazar (2018–present)', 'NAZ (2010–present)', 'Aziz (2005–2010)', 'Ecar (2015–present)', 'Edran (1984–present)', 'Gillet (1982–present)', 'Imperia Automobiles (2008–present)', 'ADK (1930)', 'Alatac (1913–1914)', 'Alberta (1906)', 'Alfa Legia (1914)', 'ALP (1920)', 'Altona (1946)', 'AMA (1913)', 'Antoine (1903)', "d'Aoust (1927)", 'Apal (1998)', 'Aquila (1903)', 'Astra (1931)', 'ATA', 'Auto Garage (1911)', 'Auto-Mixte (1906–1912)', 'Avior (1947)', 'Bastin (1909)', 'Beckett & Farlow (1908)', 'Belga (1921)', 'Belga-Rise (1935)', 'Belgica (1909)', 'Bercley (1900)', 'Bovy (1914)', 'Cambier (1898)', 'CAP (1914)', 'Catala (1914)', 'CIE (1898)', "CLA (Compagnie Liégeoise d'Automobiles) (1901)", 'Claeys-Flandria (1955)', 'Coune (1947)', 'Cyclecars R&D (1921)', 'Dasse (1924)', 'De Cosmo (1908)', 'De Wandre (1923)', 'DéChamps (1906)', 'Delecroix (1899)', 'Delin (1901)', 'Direct (1905)', 'Dyle & Bacalan (1906)', 'Escol (1938)', 'Excelsior (1904–1932)', 'Fab (1914)', 'FD (1925)', 'Fif (1914)', 'Flaid (1921)', 'FN (1935)', 'Fondu (1912)', 'Frenay (1914)', 'Germain (1901)', 'Hermes (1909)', 'Hermes-Mathis (1914)', 'Imperia (1906–1948)', 'Imperia-Abadal (1913–1917)', 'Jeecy-Vea (1926)', 'Jenatzy (Société Générale des Transports Automobiles) (1905)', 'Juwel (1928)', 'Kleinstwagen (1952)', 'Knap (moved to France in 1899 or 1900) (1909)', 'L&B', 'Linon (1914)', 'Loza (1925)', 'Matthieu (1906)', 'Matthys Frères et Osy (1927)', 'Mécanique et Moteurs (1906)', 'Meeussen (1972)', 'Métallurgique (1913)', 'Miesse (1926)', 'Minerva (1939)', 'Nagant (1927)', 'Oracle (2005)', 'P.L.M. (Keller) (1955)', 'P-M (1924)', 'Peterill (1899)', 'Pieper (1903)', 'Pipe (1922)', 'R.A.L. (1914)', 'Ranger (General Motors brand) (1970–1978)', 'Royal Star (1910)', 'Rumpf (1899)', 'S.C.H. (1928)', 'Sava (1923)', 'SOMEA', 'Speedsport (1927)', 'Springuel (1912)', 'Taunton (1922)', 'Turner-Miesse (1913)', 'Vanclee (1989)', 'Vincke (1905)', 'Vivinus (1912)', 'Widi (1960)', 'Wilford (1901)', 'Zelensis (1962)', 'PRETIS (?–1969)', 'TAS (1982–1992)', 'Abais', 'Adamo GT', 'Agrale (1982–present)', 'Americar', 'Amoritz GT', 'Avallone', 'Bianco', 'BRM Buggy (1969–present)', 'Bugre (1970–present)', 'Centaurus', 'Chamonix (1987–present)', 'Edra (1989–present)', 'Kramer', 'Lobini (2002–present)', 'Matra', 'San Vito', 'TAC (2004–present)', 'Tanger', 'Vemag', 'Villa GT', 'Volkswagen (1953–present)', 'W.W. Trevis (1998–present)', 'Dacon (1964-1996)', 'Dardo (1981)', 'Democrata (1967)', 'Engesa (1963–1993)', 'Envemo (1978–c.1994)', 'Equus Thundix', 'Fabral', 'Farus', 'FNM (1960–1963)', 'Gurgel (1966–1995)', 'Hofstetter turbo (1986–1989)', 'Miura (1977–c.1987)', 'MP Lafer (1974–c.1990)', 'Puma (1967–1997)', 'Santa Matilde (1977–c.1997)', 'Troller (1998–2021)', 'Uirapuru (1966–1968)', 'Willys', 'Litex Motors', 'SIN Cars', 'Bulgaralpine', 'Bulgarrenault', 'Moskvitch', 'Pirin-Fiat', 'Sofia', 'ElectraMeccanica (2015–present)', 'HTT (automobile) (2010–present)', 'Intermeccanica (1959–present)', 'Wingho (1999-present)', 'Acadian (1961–1971)', 'Amherst (1912)', 'Asüna (1992–1995)', 'Beaumont', 'Bourassa (1926)', 'Bricklin (1974–1975)', 'Brock (1921)', 'Brooks (1923–1926)', 'Canadian (1921)', 'Canadian Motor (1900–1902)', 'Clinton (1911–1912)', 'Colonial (1922)', 'Dominion Motors Frontenac (1931–1933)', 'Enterra (1987)', 'Envoy', 'Epic', 'Frontenac (1959–1960)', 'Gareau (1910)', 'Gray-Dort (1915–1925)', 'London Six (1922–1924)', 'Manic GT (1969–1971)', 'McLaughlin (1908–1922)', 'Meteor (1949–1976)', 'Monarch (1946–1961)', 'Moose Jaw Standard (1916–1919)', 'Queen (1901–1903)', 'Studebaker (1963–1966)', 'Tudhope (1906–1913)', 'ZENN (2006–2010)', 'BAIC Group', 'Baolong (1998–present)', 'Beijing Automotive Industry Holding Corporation\nBeijing Automobile Works (1958–present)', 'Beijing Automobile Works (1958–present)', 'BYD (2003–present)', "Chang'an Motors (1990–present)\nChanghe (since 1986)\nHafei", 'Changhe (since 1986)', 'Hafei', 'Chery (Qirui) (1997–present)', 'Dadi', 'Dongfeng (1969–present)\nDongfeng Fengshen\nVenucia (2010–present)', 'Dongfeng Fengshen', 'Venucia (2010–present)', 'First Automobile Works (FAW) (1953–present)\nFAW Tianjin (Xiali) (1986–present)\nHaima Automobile (2004–present)\nHongqi (Red Flag) (1958–present)\nHuali', 'FAW Tianjin (Xiali) (1986–present)', 'Haima Automobile (2004–present)', 'Hongqi (Red Flag) (1958–present)', 'Huali', 'Forta', 'Foton (1996–present)', 'Fudi (1996–present)', 'Fukang (company) (1990–present)', 'Fuqi', 'Geely (Jili) (1998–present)\nShanghai Maple Guorun Automobile (2003–present)\nZhejiang Geely Automobile', 'Shanghai Maple Guorun Automobile (2003–present)', 'Zhejiang Geely Automobile', 'LTI Shanghai Automobile', 'Great Wall Motors (1984–present)\nHaval', 'Haval', 'Green Field Motor (2010–present)', 'Guangzhou Automobile Industry Group (GAIG) (2000–present)\nChangfeng Motor\nLiebao\nGAC Group\nGonow\nTrumpchi\nGuangqi Honda\nEverus', 'Changfeng Motor\nLiebao', 'Liebao', 'GAC Group', 'Gonow\nTrumpchi', 'Trumpchi', 'Guangqi Honda\nEverus', 'Everus', 'Guizhou / Yunque', 'Hawtai (Huatai)', 'Huachen (Brilliance)\nJinbei (1992–present)', 'Jinbei (1992–present)', 'Huayang', 'Hwanghai', 'Icona', 'Jianghuai (JAC) (1999–present)', 'Jiangling (JMC) (1993–present)', 'Jiangnan (company) (1988–present)', 'Jonway (2005–present)', 'Kingstar (2004–present)\nLandwind', 'Landwind', 'Li Nian (Everus) (2010–present)', 'Lifan (2005–present)', 'NIO (2014–present)', 'Polarsun Automobile (Zhongshun) (2004–present)', 'Qoros (2013–present)', 'SAIC Motor\nMG Motor\nNanjing Automobile Corporation (NAC) (1947–present)\nNanjing Soyat (2004–present)\nYuejin (1995–present)\nRoewe (2006–present)\nWuling (1958–present)', 'MG Motor', 'Nanjing Automobile Corporation (NAC) (1947–present)\nNanjing Soyat (2004–present)\nYuejin (1995–present)', 'Nanjing Soyat (2004–present)', 'Yuejin (1995–present)', 'Roewe (2006–present)', 'Wuling (1958–present)', 'Shaanxi Automobile Group', 'Shuanghuan (1998–present)', 'Sichuan Tengzhong', 'Soueast Motors / Dongnan', 'Tianma (Heavenly Horse) (1995–present)', 'Tongtian (2002–present)', 'Venucia (2010–present)', 'Xinkai (1984–present)', 'Yema Auto (1994–present)', 'Youngman (2001–present)', 'Yutong Group', 'Zhonghua (1985–present)', 'Zhongxing (Zxauto) (1991–present)', 'Zhongyu (2004–present)', 'Zotye (2005–present)\nDomy Auto', 'Domy Auto', 'Crobus', 'Đuro Đaković', 'DOK-ING', 'Rimac', 'Tvornica motora zagreb', 'Tvornica Autobusa Zagreb', 'Avia (1919–present)', 'Bureko (2007–present)', 'Gordon (1997–present)', 'Jawa (1929–present)', 'Kaipan (1997–present)', 'Karosa (1896–present (since 2007 IVECO))', 'MTX / Metalex (1969–present)', 'MW Motors (2010–present)', 'Praga (1907–present)', 'Škoda (1895–present)', 'SVOS (1992–present)', 'Tatra (1850–present)', 'Aero (1929–1947)', 'Aspa (1924–25)', 'Gatter (1926–37)', 'Gnom (1921–24)', 'Hakar', 'ISIS (1922–24)', 'KAN (1911–14)', 'LIAZ (1951–2002)', 'Premier (1913–14)', 'RAF (Reichenberger Automobil Fabrik) (1907–1954)', 'Rösler & Jauernig (1896–1908)', 'Sibrava (1921–29)', 'Start (1921–31)', 'Stelka (1920–1922)', 'TAZ (1961–99)', 'Vechet (1911–14)', 'Velorex (1951–1971)', 'Walter (1909–1954)', 'Wikov (1922–35)', 'Zbrojovka Brno (1923–36)', 'PVP Karting', 'Zenvo Automotive (2004–present)', 'Anglo-Dane (1902–1917)', 'Brems (1900 and 1907)', 'Dansk (1901–1907)', 'Krampers (1890–1960)', 'Egy-Tech (2010–present)', 'Speranza (1998–present)', 'Nasr (1960–2008)', ' Nobe', 'Holland Car (2005–2013)', 'Elcat', 'Electric Raceabout (prototype, not in production)', 'Finlandia (1922–1924)', 'Korvensuu (1912–1913)', 'Sisu Auto', 'Toroidion (2015-  ,prototype, not yet in production)', 'Valmet Automotive', 'Vanaja (1943–1968)', 'Valtra', 'Veemax  (racecar, 1960s - 1978)', 'Wiima', 'Aixam', 'Alpine', 'Bolloré', 'Bugatti', 'Chatenet', 'Citroën', 'De la Chapelle', 'DS', 'Goupil', 'Ligier', 'Microcar', 'Peugeot', 'PGO', 'Renault', 'Venturi', 'Ballot (1905–1932)', 'Berliet (1899–1978)', 'Chenard-Walcker (1899–1946)', 'Darracq (1897–1902)', 'DB (1938–1961)', 'De Dion-Bouton (1883–1932)', 'Delage (1906–1953)', 'Delahaye (1894–1954)', 'Facel Vega (1939–1964)', 'Gobron-Brillié (1898–1930)', 'Hotchkiss (1903–1955)', 'Lorraine-Dietrich', 'Matra (1964–2003)', 'Mega（1919-1933）', 'Panhard (1887–2012)', 'Panhard et Levassor (1887–1940)', 'Rosengart (1927–1955)', 'Salmson (1920–1957)', 'Saviem (1955–1978)', 'Simca (1934–1979)', 'Talbot (1916–1959)', 'Talbot-Lago (1935–1959)', 'Tracta (1926–1934)', 'VELAM (1955–1959)', 'Vespa', 'Voisin (1919–1939)', '9ff', 'ABT Sportsline', 'Audi', 'Alpina', 'Artega', 'BMW', 'BMW M', 'Borgward', 'Citycom', 'CityEl', 'Ford-Werke', 'Gemballa', 'Gumpert (2004-2013, 2016-present)', 'Isdera', 'Lotec', 'Magirus', 'Maybach', 'Mercedes-AMG', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'Opel', 'Porsche', 'Ruf', 'Smart', 'Volkswagen', 'Wiesmann', 'Amphicar (1960–1968)', 'Apal', 'Auto Union (1932–1969)', 'Beck (2012)', 'DKW', 'Gatter (1952-1958) (formerly Czechoslovakia 1926-1937)', 'Glas (1883–1966)', 'Goliath (1928–1961)', 'Hansa (1905–1931)', 'Heinkel (1956–1958)', 'Horch (1904–1932)', 'Kodiak (1983-1985)', 'Lloyd (1908–1963)', 'Maybach (1909–2013)', 'Mercedes (1900–1926)', 'Messerschmitt (1953–1964)', 'NSU (1873–1969)', 'Trabant (1957–1991)', 'VW-Porsche (1969–1976)', 'Wanderer (1911–1941)', 'Wartburg (1898–1991)', 'Balkania (1945–present)', 'ELVO (1973–present)', 'Kioleides (1968–present)', 'Korres (2002–present)', 'Namco (1973–present)', 'Replicar Hellas (2007–present)', 'Saracakis (1923–present)', 'Temax (1925–present)', 'Alta (1968–1978)', 'Attica (1958–1972)', 'Autokinitoviomihania Ellados (1975–1984)', 'Automeccanica (1980–1995)', 'Balkania (1975–1995)', 'BET (1965–1975', 'Biamax (1956–1986)', 'C.AR (1970–1992)', 'Candia (1965–1990)', 'Diana (1976–1990)', 'DIM (1977–1982)', 'EBIAM (1979–1984)', 'Enfield (1973–1976)', 'Hercules (1980–1983)', 'MAVA-Renault (1979–1985)', 'MEBEA (1960–1983)', 'Neorion (1974–1975)', 'Pan-Car (1968–1994)', 'Record (1957–1999)', 'Scavas (1973–1992)', 'Styl Kar (1970)', 'Tangalakis (1935–1939)', 'Theologou (1915–1926)', 'Tejas Motors', 'Ashok Leyland ', 'DC Design', 'Eicher Motors', 'Force Motors', 'Tata Motors', 'Mahindra & Mahindra', 'Maruti Suzuki', 'KIA Motors', 'Hindustan Motors (1963–2014)', 'ICML (2012–2018)', 'Maruti (1983–2007)', 'Premier (1947–2016)', 'Reva', 'Sipani Motors (Sunrise Auto Industries) (1973–1995)', 'Standard (1949–1988)', 'Esemka', 'Fin Komodo', 'Pindad', 'Timor', 'Bahman', 'Diar', 'Iran Khodro (1962–present)', 'Khodro Kaveer', 'Kish Khodro', 'Morattab', 'MVM', 'Pars Khodro (1967–present)', 'Paykan', 'Reyan', 'SAIPA (1966–present)', 'Shahab Khodro', 'Zagross Khodro', 'Shamrock', 'TMC Costin', 'Alesbury (1907–1908)', 'GAC Ireland (1980–1986)', 'AIL', 'Plasan', 'Autocars', 'Kaiser-Ilin Industries', 'Abarth', 'ACM', 'Alfa Romeo', 'Casalini', 'Cizeta', 'Dagger', 'De Tomaso', 'DR', 'Ferrari', 'Fiat', 'Giannini', 'Giottiline', 'Grecav', 'Iveco', 'Lamborghini', 'Lancia', 'Maserati', 'Mazzanti', 'Pagani', 'Piaggio', 'Pininfarina', 'Qvale', 'ASA (1961–1969)', 'Autobianchi (1955–1995)', 'Bertone (1982–1989)', 'Bizzarrini (1964–1969)', 'Cisitalia (1946–1963)', 'Covini (1978-2016)', 'Innocenti (1920–1996)', 'Intermeccanica (moved to Canada)', 'Iso (1953–1974)', 'Karlmann', 'O.S.C.A. (1947–1967)', 'Siata (1926–1970)', 'Baby-Brousse (1964–1979)', 'Aspark', 'Daihatsu', 'Datsun', 'Dome (1975-present)', 'Englon', 'Lexus', 'Honda', 'Acura', 'Isuzu', 'Mazda', 'Mini', 'Mitsubishi', 'Mitsuoka', 'Nissan', 'Infiniti', 'Proton', 'Renault', 'SEAT', 'Subaru', 'Suzuki', 'Toyota', 'Yamaha Motor', 'Autozam (1989–1998)', 'Colt (1974–1984) (cars produced and exported by Mitsubishi Motors and imported into the UK by the Colt Car Company and marketed under the Colt brand)', 'ɛ̃fini (1991–1997)', 'Eunos (1989–1996)', 'Hino (1961–1967)', 'Prince (1952–1966)', 'Scion (2003–2016)', 'Toyopet', 'Mobius (2013–present)', 'Nyayo (1986–1999)', 'Orca', 'Assal', 'Bufori', 'Proton', 'Perodua', 'TD2000', 'Inokom', 'Naza', 'Hicom', 'Mildef', 'Mykar', 'Autobuses King', 'Cimex', 'Dina', 'FANASA', 'Grupo Electrico Motorizado', 'Mastretta', 'VAM', 'Vhul', 'Zacua', 'Matchedje Motors (2014–2017) owned by China Tong Jian Investment – built rebadged Fudi F16 pickups.', 'Uri-Automobile (1995–2008 moved to South Africa)', 'Hulas Motors', 'Donkervoort', "Van Doorne's Automobiel Fabrieken", 'Spyker (1999–present)', 'Vencer', 'DAF', 'Spyker (1899–1926)', 'Eysink', 'Almac (1985–present)', 'Alternative Cars (1984–present)', 'Chevron (1984–present)', 'Fraser (1988–present)', 'Hulme (2005–present)', 'Leitch (1986–present)', 'Saker (1989–present)', 'Anziel (1967)', 'Beattie (1997–2001) thence Redline', 'Carlton (1922–1928)', 'Cobra (1983–1990)', 'Crowther (1968–1978)', 'De Joux (1970)', "Dennison (1900–1905) – New Zealand's first indigenous car", 'Everson (1935–1989)', 'Heron (1964–1990)', 'Marlborough (1912–1922) thence Carlton', 'McRae (1990–2003)', 'Mistral (1957–1960)', 'Redline (2001–2009)', 'Steel Brothers (1973–1981)', 'Trekka (1966–1973)', 'UltraCommuter (2006–2013)', 'Wood (1901–1903)', 'Izuogu (1997–2006)', 'Innoson Vehicle Manufacturing', 'Pyeonghwa Motors', 'Pyongsang Auto Works', 'Sungri Motors', 'Kongsberg', 'Bjering', 'Buddy', 'Geijer', 'Norsk', 'Think', 'Troll', 'Atlas Honda', 'Honda Atlas Cars Pakistan', 'FAW Pakistan', 'Ghandhara Nissan', 'Ghandhara Industries', 'Heavy Industries Taxila', 'Hinopak', 'Master', 'Millat Tractors', 'Pak Suzuki', 'Indus Motors Company', 'Yamaha Motor Pakistan', 'Sazgar', 'Hyundai Nishat Motors', 'Kia Lucky Motors', 'United Auto Industries', 'Prince DFSK', 'MG JW Automobile', 'Adam Motor Company (Defunct)', 'Nexus Automotive (Defunct)', 'Dewan Farooque Motors (Defunct)', 'Arrinera', 'FSO', 'Melex', 'Polski Fiat (1932–1939, 1968–1992)', 'UMM (União Metalo-Mecânica) (1978–2001)', 'Portaro (1975–1995)', 'Dacia (1966–present)', 'Ford România S.A. (2008–present)', 'Oltcit (1976–1991)', 'ARO (1957–2006)', 'Derways (2003–present)', 'GAZ (1932–present)', 'Lada (1966–present)', 'UAZ (1941–present)', 'ZiL (1916–present)', 'Izh (1965–2008)', 'Moskvitch (1929–2010)', 'Russo-Balt (1894–1929/2006)', 'Marussia (2007–2014)', 'FCA Srbija (2008–present)', 'Zastava TERVO (2017–present)', 'IDA-Opel (1977–1992)', 'Yugo (1944–2008)', 'Zastava (1953–2008)', 'Revoz', 'Atax (1938–1949)', 'TAM (1947–2011)', 'Birkin (1982–present)', 'Harper Sports Cars (2014–present)', 'Perana (2007–present)', 'Puma (1973–1974, 1989–1991, 2006–present)', 'Shaka (1995–present)', 'Superformance (1996–present)', 'Uri International Vehicle & Equipment Marketing (2008–present)', 'Badsey (1979–1983, then the company moved to the USA', 'Eagle', 'GSM (1958–1964)', 'Hayden Dart (1997–2003)', 'Hi-Tech (1992–1996)', 'Optimal Energy (2008–2012)', 'Perana (1967–1996; a famous Ford manufacturer, today only active as a Ford dealer)', 'Protea (1957–1958)', 'Ranger (1968–1973)', 'Sao (1985–1994)', 'CT&T', 'Galloper', 'Genesis', 'Hyundai', 'Kia', 'Renault Samsung', 'Ssangyong', 'Edison Motors', 'Asia (1965–1999)', 'Daewoo (1983–2002)', 'GMK (1972–1976)', 'Saehan (1976–1983)', 'Saenara (1962–1965)', 'Proto (1997–2017)', 'Shinjin (1965–1972)', 'Aspid', 'Comarth', 'Cupra', 'DSD Design and Motorsport', 'GTA Motor', 'Hurtan', 'SEAT', 'Spania GTA', 'Tramontana (sports car)', 'Tauro Sport Auto', 'UROVESA', 'Hispano Suiza (Planned Revival in 2019)', 'Pegaso', 'Santana', 'Volvo Cars (1927–present)', 'Koenigsegg (1994–present)', 'Polestar (1996–present)', 'NEVS (2012–present) (bought by Saab)', 'Von Braun Holding Company (2014–present)', 'Allevo (1890–1916) / (made cars 1903–1907)', 'Vagnsaktiebolaget I Södertelge (later VABIS, then Scania-Vabis)', 'Rengsjöbilen (1914–1916)', 'Saab (1945–2012)', 'Hult Healey (1984–1990)', 'Jösse Car (1994–1999)', 'Tjorven (1968–1971)', 'MBM (1960–1967)', 'Monteverdi (1967–1984)', 'Ranger (General Motors brand) (1970–1975)', 'CMC (1973–present)', 'Formosa', 'Luxgen', 'Thunder Power', 'Tobe', 'Yue Long/Yulon/YLN (affiliated to Nissan)', 'Akepanich', 'C-FEE', 'Cherdchai', 'Deva', 'Kwaithong', 'Mine', 'Siam V.M.C.', 'Thai Rung', 'Vera', 'Barkia (2010–present)', 'Industries Mécaniques Maghrébines (1982–1988, 1991–present)', 'Wallyscar (2007–present)', 'Anadol', 'Devrim', 'Diardi', 'Etox', 'EVT S1', 'Imza', 'Özaltin', 'Sazan', 'Tofaş (1968–date)', 'TOGG', 'Kiira', 'ZAZ (1923–present)', 'Devel Motors', 'Shayton', 'W Motors', 'Zarooq Motors', 'AC Cars', 'Arash', 'Ariel (1991–present)', 'Aston Martin (1913–present)', 'BAC', 'Bentley (1919–present)', 'Bristol', 'Caterham Cars (1957–present)', 'David Brown (2013–present)', 'Dendrobium', 'Farbio', 'Ford', 'Ginetta (1958–present)', 'Jaguar (1935–present)', 'Jowett (1906–1954)', 'Keating Supercars (2006-present)', 'Lagonda', 'Land Rover (1948–present)', 'Lister', 'London Electric Vehicle Company (LEVC) (2013–present)', 'Lotus (1952–present)', 'Mini', 'McLaren (2010–present)', 'Morgan (1910–present)', 'Noble (1999–present)', 'Radical (1997–present)', 'Rolls-Royce (1904–present)', 'Trident', 'TVR (1946–2006,2013-present)', 'Vauxhall (1903–present)', 'AC', 'Allard (1945–1957)', 'Alvis', 'Armstrong Siddeley', 'Ascari (1995–2010)', 'Austin', 'Austin-Healey (1952–1972)', 'Berkeley (1956–1960)', 'Bond', 'Bristol (1945–2020)', 'British Salmson (1934–1939)', 'Buckler (1947–1962)', 'Chambers Motors (1904–1929)', 'Chrysler Europe (1976–1979)', 'Daimler', 'Dutton', 'Elva', 'Fairthorpe', 'Farboud Limited (1999-2006)', 'Frazer Nash (1925–1957)', 'Gilbern (1959–1973)', 'Gordon-Keeble', 'Healey', 'Hillman', 'Humber', 'Invicta', 'Jensen', 'Jowett (1906–1954)', 'Lanchester', 'Lea-Francis', 'Lloyd (1936–1950)', 'Lotus-Cortina', 'Marauder (1950–1952)', 'MG (1924–2011)', 'Metropolitan (1953–1961)', 'Morris (1913–1984)', 'Nash-Healey (1951–1954)', 'Ohio Electric (circa 1917)', 'Panther (1972–1990)', 'Paramount (1950–1956)', 'Peel Engineering Company (1955–1969)', 'Peerless (1957–1960)', 'Princess (1957–1960) (1975–1981)', 'Reliant', 'Riley (1907–1969)', 'Rover (1904–2005)', 'RW (1983–2000)', 'Singer', 'Standard', 'Sunbeam', 'Sunbeam-Talbot', 'Swallow (1954–1955)', 'Talbot', 'Tornado', 'Triumph', 'Trojan', 'Turner', 'Tyrrell', 'Vanden Plas', 'Warwick (1960–1962)', 'Wolseley', 'AM General', 'Anteros (2005–present)', 'Aurica (2010–present)', 'Bollinger Motors (2014-present)', 'Bremach (2009–present)', 'Buick (1903–present)', 'BXR (2008–present)', 'Cadillac (1902–present)', 'Chevrolet (1911–present)', 'Chrysler (1925–present)', 'Custom Crafted Cars (2013–present)', 'Dodge (1900–present)', 'Elio Motors (2009–present)', 'Equus Automotive (2014–present)', 'E-Z-GO (1954–present)', 'Falcon (2009–present)', 'Faraday (2014–present)', 'Ford (1903–present)', 'General Motors (1908–present)', 'Genovation', 'GMC (1913–present)', 'Hummer (1992–2010; 2020–present)', 'Opel (1941-present) (from Germany)', 'Hennessey (1991–present)', 'Humble Motors (2020-present)', 'Jeep (1941–present)', 'Karma (2016–present) (Formerly Fisker inc.)', 'Lincoln (1917–present)', 'Local (2007—present)', 'Lucid (2014–present)', 'Lyons (2011–present)', 'Niama-Reisser (2005–present)', 'Panoz (1989–present)', 'Polaris (1954–present)\nGEM', 'GEM', 'Racefab (1991–present)', 'RAESR (2014–present)', 'Ram Trucks (2010–present)', 'Rezvani (2014–present)', 'Rivian (2009–present)', 'Rossion (2007–present)', 'Saleen (1980–present)', 'Scuderia Cameron Glickenhaus', 'Shelby American (1962–present)', 'SSC (1999–present)', 'Tesla (2003–present)', 'Trion Supercars (2012–present)', 'Vehicle Production Group (2011-2013)', 'Zimmer (1978–1988, 1997–present)', 'Ajax (1925-1926)', 'AMC (1954–1987)', 'American Simplex (1906–1910) (renamed to Amplex in 1910)', 'Amplex (1910–1915) (previously known as American Simplex)', 'Auburn', 'Checker', 'Cord', 'Crosley', 'DeLorean Motor Company (1981–1983)', 'DeSoto (1928–1960)', 'Detroit Electric (1907–1939)', 'Devon (2008-2013)', 'Duesenberg', 'Eagle (1987–1998)', 'Edsel (1958–1960)', 'Frazer', 'Fisker (2011–2014)', 'Geo (General Motors brand) (1989–1997)', 'Henry J (1950–1954)', 'Hudson (1909–1957)', 'Hupmobile (1909–1939)', 'Imperial (1955–1975, 1981–1983) (Chrysler Corporation brand – Imperial was also used as a Chrysler model name in certain other years)', 'Jordan', 'Kaiser', 'LaFayette', 'LaSalle (1927–1940)', 'Marmon (1851-1933)', 'Marquette (General Motors brand)', 'Maxwell', 'Mercer (1909–1925)', 'Mercury (1938–2011)', 'Merkur (1985–1989)', 'Moon', 'Mosler (1993–2013)', 'Nash', 'Navistar International', 'Oakland (1908–1931)', 'Oldsmobile (1897–2004)', 'Packard (1899–1958)', 'Plymouth (1928–2001)', 'Pontiac (1926–2010)', 'Rambler (1897–1914 & 1958–1969)', 'Reliable Dayton (1906–1909)', 'Saturn (1985–2010)', 'Staver (1907–1914)', 'Stearns-Knight', 'Studebaker (1852–1967)', 'Vector (1989-1993)', 'Willys (1908–1963)', 'Nordex (1962–present)', 'Dellepiane (1980)', 'El Terruno (1960)', 'Grumett (1960–1982)', 'Guitolar (1970–2004)', 'Indio (1969–1977)', 'Industrias WARV (1966–1972)', 'Lima (1970–1980)', 'Mauser', 'Metalurgica Laguarda (1963)', 'Taller Danree y Silveira (1950–1960)', 'ChienThang', 'La Dalat', 'THACO', 'VinFast', 'Vinaxuki (2004–2015)']
```